# Have a static create method instead of a constructor in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, model

I'm new to Typescript, and I'm making a class that can return an instance based of other data (firebase data in my example).

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the fromFirebaseUser method to use a create method instead of call `new User()`.

*User.ts*

```
import {User as FirebaseUser} from '@firebase/auth';

class User {

    public uid: string;
    public displayName: string;

    constructor(uid: string, displayName: string ) {
        this.uid = uid
        this.displayName = displayName
    }

    public static fromFirebaseUser(user: FirebaseUser): User {
        return new User(user.uid, user.displayName ?? '')
    }
}
```

I started with the definition as follows, where the return type should be the calling class, and the input will be an object with the required data? I know I should be checking the data object to be equal to the User class properties, but that's where I'm stuck.

```
public static create(data): User {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have `Users` and `Posts`

### Users

```js
type UserData = {
  uid: string;
  displayName: string;
}

class User {
  public uid: string;
  public displayName: string;

  constructor(uid: string, displayName: string ) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.displayName = displayName;
  }
}
```

### Posts

```js
type PostData = {
  uid: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

class Post {
  public uid: string;
  public title: string;
  public body: string;

  constructor(uid: string, title: string, body: string ) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
  }
}
```

## 1st Solution - `DataFactory` with a static `create` method

```js
class DataFactory {
  public static create(data: UserData): User;
  public static create(data: PostData): Post;
  public static create(data: UserData | PostData) {
    if ('displayName' in data)
        return new User(data.uid, data.displayName);
    if ('title' in data)
        return new Post(data.uid, data.title, data.body);
    throw new Error('Unknown data type');
  }
}
```

This `DataFactory` ensures that the result of `create` is properly typed:

```js
const user = DataFactory.create({
  uid: 'u123',
  displayName: 'Miguel Stevens'
});
console.log(user);
// User: { "uid": "u123", "displayName": "Miguel Stevens" }
const post = DataFactory.create({
  uid: 'p123',
  title: 'My first post',
  body: 'Blablabla'
});
console.log(post);
// Post: { "uid": "p123", "title": "My first post", "body": "Blablabla" }
```

But, you could definitely have cases where two data types share the same data signature...

## 2nd Solution - Using Firebase collection as data type

Instead of just using the data coming back from Firebase, you could also use the Firebase collection as a data type:

```js
enum Collection {
  users= 'users',
  posts= 'posts',
}
```

Your `create` method now takes both the collection as data type and the data coming from Firebase:

```js
class DataFactory {
  public static create(type: Collection.users, data: UserData): User;
  public static create(type: Collection.posts, data: PostData): Post;
  public static create(type: Collection, data: UserData & PostData) {
    switch (type) {
      case Collection.users:
        return new User(data.uid, data.displayName);
      case Collection.posts:
        return new Post(data.uid, data.title, data.body);
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown data type');
    }
  }
}
```

This `DataFactory` still ensures that the result of `create` is properly typed:

```js
const user = DataFactory.create(Collection['users'], {
  uid: 'u456',
  displayName: 'Jar Jar Binks'
});
console.log(user);
// User: { "uid": "u456", "displayName": "Jar Jar Binks" }
const post = DataFactory.create(Collection['posts'], {
  uid: 'p456',
  title: 'My second post',
  body: 'Blablabla'
});
console.log(post);
// Post: { "uid": "p456", "title": "My second post", "body": "Blablabla" }
```

Comment: Can the data types be left out in TS? (UserType, PostType) Is it possible to use the class as the interface/contract for the data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What `UserType` and `PostType` are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry Thierry, I meant UserData and PostData

Comment: Oh, ok. The idea of `UserData` (type) vs `User` (model class) is that `UserData` is the signature of the data you get from Firebase, which could have a signature different from your model class. The first example that comes to mind would be the Firestore `Timestamp` that you might want to convert into a `Date` when you create your Business Object.

Comment: The issue I can see now is that you have to declare any change to the user data in two places, once in the UserData and once in the User model, since they have duplicate model attributes listed there.

Comment: This will be needed if the interfaces of your Firestore Data and your model classes are different, correct?
If they really are the same, you could have `User` extending `UserData`.

Comment: Yes, I see now! Thanks